# Removing xmlns from added SOAP header

Tags: soap, jax-ws, soap-client

I'm using a SOAP jaxws java client to query the customer WebServices.

the customer wants me to add a header containing a token to be validated for each request. After several searches on how to add a header to each request I arrived [here](https://gist.github.com/jeffbicca/7753014).

This configuration works fine, I just modify a little bit the handler class as follows:

```
SOAPEnvelope envelope = msg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
SOAPFactory factory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
SOAPElement tokenElem = factory.createElement("srtoken");

tokenElem.addTextNode("123456789123456789");
       
SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader(); // an header is already present, if I try to create a new one I obtain the error 'header already exists'
              
header.addChildElement(tokenElem);
```

Now this solution works pretty well because the result request is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <srtoken xmlns="">123456789123456789</srtoken> <!-- problem is here, I don't want xmlns="" but just the tag <srtoken>
 </SOAP-ENV:Header>
 <S:Body>
  <method xmlns="http://some.path.it/AG/AnagraficaService" xmlns:ns2="http://some.path.it/wz/ns/ag" xmlns:ns3="http://some.path.it/wz/exception">
    <s1easgi>
      <abi>5</abi>
      <id>8</id>
    </s1easgi>
    <agra></agra>
  </method>
 </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

How can I solve that?